# Assigning an ID to clusters of row values in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, uniqueidentifier

I am new to R programming (been programming in SAS my whole life), and I have what I think is a basic question to which I have not been able to find the answer (have found answers to similar questions but not this one).

Imagine that we have a binary variable (which we will call "v1") that can have a value of either 0 or 1.  I would like to create a new variable (which we will call "v2") that takes on the value of a unique cluster ID every time a new value of 1 appears or a string of 1s appear after a 0.  Ultimately, I would like to create "v2" from v1 as follows:

```
Obs v1  v2
1   0   NA
2   0   NA
3   1   1
4   1   1
5   0   NA
6   1   2
7   0   NA
8   1   3
9   1   3
10  1   3
11  0   NA
12  1   4
```

If someone could shed some light on this, I would be very grateful.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

This will do the trick.  It sets the groups equal to the cumulative sum of the number of increases by 1 in the values of v1, then sets the 0s back to NA.

```
df$v2 <- cumsum(c(df$v1[1]==1,diff(df$v1)==1))
df$v2[df$v1==0] <- NA
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue if the first element of v1 is 1.

Comment: Yes - sorry - amended above.

Comment: Variation on this theme - `as.numeric(factor(replace(cumsum(!df$v1), !df$v1, NA)))`

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So for a given `v1`:

```
 v1<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
 v1_sum <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(1:length(v1)),function(x) sum(v1[1:x])))#create the cumulative sum per index 
 v1_sum[v1==0] <- NA#imputing NA values to v1_sum when v1 is 0
 v1_sum_new_vals <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(1:length(v1_sum)),function(x) {sum(is.na(v1_sum[1:x]))-1}))#cumulative sum of NA's per index 
 v2 <- ifelse(!is.na(v1_sum),v1_sum_new_vals,v1_sum)#imputing new values based on a condition
```

Putting all together yields

```
 df<-data.frame(v1,v2)
 df
v1 v2
1   0 NA
2   0 NA
3   1  1
4   1  1
5   0 NA
6   1  2
7   0 NA   
8   1  3
9   1  3
10  1  3
11  0 NA
12  1  4
```

Comment: Thanks very much!